# equivalent $NFA$s

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, automata

I have a $NFA$ named $A$, with number of states $n$.

And I got another $NFA$ name $B$ with number of states $k$.

I want to check $L(A)=L(B)$.

My question is how long should I go. What is the longest word I should check.

Let say  $\exists x:\forall w\in \Sigma^*, |w|<x: A(w)=B(w)$

which means if $A$ accept $w$ so do $B$ and the other way around.

how big should be $x$ so I can tell for sure that $L(A)=L(B)$?

I think it somewhere around $max(2^n,2^k)$ but have no clue how to prove it.

Thanks

Comment: With a non-deterministic finite automaton $C$ of size $(n+1)2^{k+1}$, you can recognize the language $L(A) \backslash L(B)$. If it does not accept any word with length at most $(n+1)2^{k+1}$, then for any word with greater length, the accepting path in $C$ contains a loopless accepting subpath, thus with length at most $(n+1)2^{k+1}$, which is impossible. Thus you need only to check on words with size $\leq (n+1)2^{k+1}$ to ensure that $L(A) \backslash L(B)$. Finally, your quantity is $2^{k+n+1}\max\left(\frac{k+1}{2^k},\frac{n+1}{2^n}\right).$

Comment: how do you build the automaton $C$?

Comment: Add a “garbage” state to $B$ and $A$, making it complete, and name the result $B_1$, $A_1$. Determinize $B_1$ into a deterministic finite complete automaton $B_2$ (with $2^{k+1}$ states). $C$ is the product of $A_1$ and $B_2$, where a state $(a,b) \in C$ is accepting iff $a \in A_1$ is accepting and $b \in B_2$ is not accepting.

Comment: what do you mean by C is the product of A and B? we can assume they both complete its ok no need to add a "garbage" state

Comment: The set of states of $C$ is the set of all $(a,b)$ where $a$ is a state of $A$ and $b$ a state of $B_2$. For any letter $s$, any $s$-transitions $a \rightarrow a’$ in $A_1$, $b \rightarrow b’$ in $B_2$, there is a $s$-transition $(a,b) \rightarrow (a’,b’)$ in $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us determenize both $A$ and $B$ into $C$ and $D$ with $2^n$ and $2^k$ states (and make sure that sets of states of $C$ and $D$ are distjoint) . Let us unite $C$ and $D$ into single automata $E$ with $2^n + 2^k$ states. Now, any two distinguishable states of DFA with $x$ states can be distinguished with word with length at most $x - 2$, so if $A$ and $B$ are distinguishable, so states of $E$ corresponding to initial states of $A$ and $B$ are distinguishable too (with the same words), so there is word with length at most $2^n + 2^k - 2$ that distinguishes $A$ and $B$.

Best lower bound I can come up with is much lower - just $n + k - 2$,  though it's enough to consider DFA to achieve it. Assume $n < k$, let $A$ have states $q_1, \ldots, q_n$ with transitions $q_1 \to_{0,1} q_1$, $q_{i - 1} \to_0 q_i$ and $q_i \to_1 q_{i - 1}$ for $i \leqslant n$ and $q_n \to_0 q_n$.
Let $B$ have states $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ with transitions $p_1 \to_{0,1} p_1$, $p_{i - 1} \to_0 p_i$ for $i < k$, p_{i} \to_1 p_{i - 1}$ for $i \leqslant n$, $p_i \to p_{n - 1}$ for $n < i < k$ and $p_k \to_{0,1} p_k$.
Then $A$ accepts string $0^{k - 1} 1^{n - 1}$, but $B$ rejects it, while they agree on any shorter string.

The gap between $n + k - 2$ and $2^n + 2^k - 2$ is quite significant, but for now I have no idea how to decrease it.